# $x^5-209x+56$ admits two roots whose product is $1$, find them.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> $x^5-209x+56$  admits two roots whose product is $1$, find them.

I am reading the book (21 Aulas de matmática Olímpica - C. Shyne) and it has some questions so hard to me that I just gave up solving and this is one of them. Can anybody cast some light?

Comment: plot https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+x%5E5+%E2%88%92+209+x+%2B+56%3D0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are given that $x^5-209x+56$ has a factor of the form $x^2+ax+1$. Therefore,

$$x^5-209x+56=(x^2+ax+1)(x^3+bx^2+cx+d)$$

Opening the brackets you get
$$x^5-209x+56=x^5+(a+b)x^4+(1+ab+c)x^3+(b+ac+d)x^2+(c+ad)x+d$$

This gives
$$a+b=0 \\
1+ab+c=0 \\
b+ac+d=0 \\
c+ad=-209 \\
d=56$$

Plugging $d=56$ and $b=-a$ in the other equations we get
$$
1+c=a^2 \\
56=a-ac \\
c+56a=-209$$

Subtracting the first and last equations you get a quadratic in a which is easy to solve.

Comment: Therefore I select $a=-52$.  How to distinguish the roots for $a$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi For each solution you must have $$1+c=a^2 \\
56=a-ac \\
c+56a=-209$$ You can actually ignore the third equation since first and third are equivalent to first and the quadratic.

Comment: Don't tell me in the comment.  Demonstrate it in the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @OscarLanzi $$56 = a(1-c)\implies 56a=1-c^2\implies 209+c=c^2-1.$$ Solve for $c$ by the quadratic formula, and it follows that $c=15$ and $a=-4$. Or, as N.S. suggested, you could have done $1-56a=a^2+209$ by subtracting the third equation from the first. Wasn't too hard.

Comment: Again, this should be demonstrated in the answer, not in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

Let the two roots be $\frac{1}{a}$ and $a.$ Then we have:

$$a^5-209a+56=0 \space(1)$$ and $$56a^{5}-209a^4+1=0 \space(2).$$

Then  $56\times (1)-(2)$ and simplifying gives: $$a^4
 −56a+15=0 \space(3)$$

On the other hand $\frac{(1)-56\times(3)}{-209a}$ gives:
$$15a^4-56a^3+1=0 \space(4)$$

Finally we can eliminate the $a^4$ term from the last two equations to obtain $a^3-15a+4=0$ and similarly we can also eliminate the constant term (i.e $(3)-15\times (4)$) and then simplify to obtain $4a^3-15a^2+1=0.$

Then eliminating $a^3$ gives $a^2-4a+1=0,$ which is a quadratic!

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the beginning of [Äres's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816725/16078): if $r$ and $1/r$ are the two roots in question, then we have both $r^5-209r+56=0$ and $56r^5-209r^4+1=0$. The Euclidean algorithm for polynomials finds that $\gcd(r^5-209r+56,56r^5-209r^4+1)=r^2-4r+1$, and so the roots of this quadratic polynomial, namely $r=2\pm\sqrt3$, must be the roots in question.

---

*Initial answer:* Here's an annoying way but algorithmic to solve it: if the two roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha\beta=1$, then we know that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = x^2+ax+1$ for some $a$. Dividing $x^5-209x+56$ by $x^2+ax+1$ yields
$$
x^3 - ax^2 + (a^2-1)x - a(a^2-2) + \frac{(a^4-3 a^2-208)x+(a^3-2 a+56)}{a x+x^2+1}.
$$
So if $x^2+ax+1$ is to divide $x^5-209x+56$, then we must have $(a^4-3 a^2-208)x+(a^3-2 a+56)=0$, or equivalently $a^4-3 a^2-208=0$ and $a^3-2 a+56$. But we can work out that $\gcd(a^4-3 a^2-208,a^3-2 a+56) = a+4$, and so $a=-4$ is the only solution. The roots of $x^2-4x+1$, namely $2\pm\sqrt3$, are therefore roots of $x^5-209x+56$ as well, as can be verified directly.

Comment: You blew my cover!

Answer (score 4):

Seek a factor having the form $x^2-ax+1$, whose roots are the ones we want.

By polynomial division we get

$(x^5-209x+56)=(x^3+ax^2+(a^2-1)x+(a^3-2a))(x^2-ax+1)+\color{blue}{(a^4-3a^2-208)x+(a^3-2a-56)}$

The remainder, in blue, must be zero for all $x$, so the linear and constant coefficients must be zero:

$a^4-3a^2-208=0$

$a^3-2a-56=0$

You are to find this common root, which happens to be a rational root for $a$ (not $x$).

> Thereby solving $(a^2)^2-3(a^2)-208=0$ gives $a^2\in\{-13,16\},a\in\{\pm\sqrt{13}i,\pm4\}$.  Of these only $a=4$ also solves $a^3-2a-56=0$.  Thus the sought quadratic factor is $x^2-4x+1$ giving the roots $2\pm\sqrt3$.

Comment: did you mean the sought quadratic factor is $x^\color{red}2-4x+1$?

Comment: Mistyped, sorry.

Comment: Another way could be multiplying both sides of $a^3-2a-56=0$ by $a$ and subtracting the result from $a^4-3a^2-208=0$, thereby getting $a^2-56a+208=0$ whose solutions are $4$ and $52$ but only $4$ solves both originating equations.

Answer (score 3):

Let one of the roots be $k$. Then the other is $1/k$. We can factor your polynomial as
\begin{equation}
x^5-209x+56 = (x-k)(x-\frac{1}{k})(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)
\end{equation}
for real $a, b, c$. Easy to see that $c=56$. Expanding the right hand side and equating coefficients, one can arrive at
\begin{align}
a&=k+\frac{1}{k}\\
56-ab+a&=0\\
b-a^2+1&=0.
\end{align}
Solve the system consisting of the last two equations any way you want; the only real roots are given by $a=4, b=15$. From here
\begin{equation}
k+\frac{1}{k}=4 \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad k^2-4k+1=0.
\end{equation}
The roots are $k_1=2+\sqrt{3}, k_2=2-\sqrt{3}$. Indeed, $k_1k_2=1$.

Comment: You too!  Blew my cover!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_1,x_2$ are roots such that $x_1\cdot x_2 = 1$, then
$$
{x_1}^5 = 209 x_1 - 56\\
{x_2}^5 = 209 x_2 - 56
$$
so by multiplying both equations
$${(x_1 x_2)}^5 = 1 = (209x_1 -56)(209x_2-56) = 209^2\overbrace{x_1x_2}^1 -56\cdot209(x_1+x_2) + 56^2\\= 46817 - 11704 (x_1+x_2) \implies x_1+x_2 = 4$$
Now substituting $x_2 = \frac{1}{x_1}$, we get
$$x_1 + \frac{1}{x_1} = 4 \implies {x_1}^2-4x_1+1 = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula you get $x_1 = 2\pm\sqrt{3}$ which then you can verify that leads to the roots being $2+\sqrt{3}$ and $2-\sqrt{3}$ in some order.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $a$ and $\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{a}\end{aligned}$ are roots of $x^5 - 209x + 56$, i.e., $\begin{aligned} a^5 - 209a + 56 = \frac{1}{a^5} - \frac{209}{a} + 56 = 0\end{aligned}$. From the first equality we get

$\begin{aligned}
a^5 - 209a = \frac{1}{a^5} - \frac{209}{a} &\implies\\
\Big(a^5 - \frac{1}{a^5}\Big) -209\Big(a - \frac{1}{a}\Big) = 0 &\implies\\
\Big(a - \frac{1}{a}\Big)\Big(a^4 + a^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a^4} - 209 \Big) = 0\\
\end{aligned}$

It's easy to see that $\begin{aligned}a + \frac{1}{a} \neq 0\end{aligned} \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$, so we have

$\begin{aligned}
a^4 + a^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a^4} - 209 = 0 &\implies\\
\Big(a^4 + 2 + \frac{1}{a^4}\Big) + \Big(a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2}\Big) -2 - 208 = 0 &\implies\\
\Big(a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2}\Big)^2 + \Big(a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2}\Big) - 210 = 0 &\implies\\
\end{aligned}$

Solving for $\begin{aligned}a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2}\end{aligned}$ (which is non negative) gives

$\begin{aligned}a^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4\cdot 210}}{2} = 14\end{aligned}$

So $a^4 + 1 = 14a^2$. Solving for $a^2$ gives

$\begin{aligned}a^2 = \frac{14\pm\sqrt{14^2-4}}{2} = 7\pm4\sqrt{3} = (2\pm\sqrt{3})^2 \therefore a = 2\pm\sqrt{3}\end{aligned}$.

so we have the final answer.